# Как получить список таблиц в базе данных Oracle?

Tags: oracle, sql

Идет подключение к базе данных. Схема заранее неизвестна. Как узнать, какие в базе есть таблицы?

```
OracleDataSource ods = new OracleDataSource();

// Здесь остальные параметры подключения
// ...

Connection conn = ods.getConnection();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выполнить запрос "select * from ALL_TABLES" и осмыслить результаты

Comment: Работает.

        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select table_name from all_tables");

        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
        }

        rs.close();
        stmt.close();

Comment: Такие эксперименты удобно проводить в Oracle sqldeveloper или прсто из sqlpus.

Answer (score 0):

Таблица и название схемы:

select table_name, tablespace_name from ALL_TABLES;

Или можешь вывести все необходимые поля. Узнать их можно:

describe all_tables;

а что в них записано можно понять по названию этих полей.